# Perl: reference to a hash to pass to another routine

Tags: perl, hash

In code that uploads excel spreadsheets it gives me the data in array ref:

```
for( @{$listref} ){...
```

I access it with `$_->{'whateverthehashkeyis'}` and have no problem.

What I need to do is pass the hash I am accessing in the current iteration of the loop to another subroutine.

This is where I am having problems.  I have tried different things with no luck.

This DOES NOT work, but it should be an example of what I need to do

```
%args = @{$_};

$results = &format_trading_card_preview_item(\%args);
....
sub format_trading_card_preview_item
{
    my %args = shift;
```

I think what I need to do is dereference the hash to send it over. Is that right?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Welcome to the site. This question is getting close votes. It's possible there are other questions that already address this issue - you may want to use the search box. However, I've marked up your code and cleaned up the grammar in an effort to make it easier to read.  If you don't like what I've done, you can rollback my changes and/or make your own via an [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34439203/edit). Also, please have a look a the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to get a better idea of how the site works.

Comment: Thank you @GreenMatt. I did spend more than an hour on Google and on this site looking for answers. Thanks for cleaning up my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `$listref` is a reference to an array of hash references.

If you need to use the variable holding the hash references then it is better if you name that variable instead of using the default scalar `$_`

There is also no point in dereferencing the hash and copying it to `%args`, only to take a reference to *that* hash and pass it as a parameter to your subroutine

And it is wrong to call a subroutine with an ampersand `&` character, and has been so ever since Perl v5.5 landed over seventeen years ago

Your loop should look like this

```
for my $item ( @$listref ) {
    format_trading_card_preview_item($item);
}
```

Within the subroutine, it depends a lot on what you want to do with the hash passed in, but you don't say anything about that, so it's probably best to leave it as a reference and write

```
sub format_trading_card_preview_item {
    my ($item) = @_;
    ...
}
```

or you could use the *statement modifier* form of `for`, like this

```
format_trading_card_preview_item($_) for @$listref;
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Borodin...I thought I was close :-)

Comment: @MikeCarvilleGleTech: You're welcome. Note that I've added an alternative, more concise form that you may prefer

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, you don't need to dereference the hash reference in order to pass it to another subroutine. Creating a shallow copy and then taking a reference to that new hash is inefficient, but it would technically work just fine.

However, your problem is that you're confusing hashes and arrays by using the syntax to dereference an array reference on something that is actually a hash reference. In fact, you should have gotten an error message basically saying the same thing:

> Not an ARRAY reference at foo.pl line ...

What you actually want to do is something like this:

```
for my $href (@$listref) {  # variable names could be better
    # do something
    my $results = format_trading_card_preview_item($href);
    # do something else
}

sub format_trading_card_preview_item {
    my $args = shift;
    print $args->{foo};
    return 42;
}
```

Check out [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) and [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) for more information on Perl references and nested data structures.

Comment: Thank You @Matt Jacob The answer works as well as the other. I appreciate you taking the time to explain it.